# Comparing JMS to AMQP

Tags: java, jms, amqp

I was googling around to search for what makes them different. I have used RabbitMQ and ZeroMQ for some of my projects. Knowing that JMS still exists and people use it I begin to wonder why? What motivates the usage of JMS are there any performance, architectural, or any advantages? I have no knowledge of JMS but if what I understand is true why would somebody bound himself to a java specific technology?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JMS and AMQP aren't really comparable. JMS is an API; AMQP is a protocol. It is possible to write a JMS implementation that uses AMQP. Indeed, [people have](https://github.com/imatix/openamq-jms).

Moreover, it is possible to write JMS implementations that use other protocols - and of course, [numerous](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq) [people](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.itamfbi.doc_5.1/ADM51mst40.htm) [have](http://tibcoadmin.com/tibco/ems/what-is-tibco-ems/).

The goal of JMS is to put a uniform API over all these different messaging protocols. This makes life easier for programmers, who can learn one API, and then have a reasonable chance of using any message queue they come across.

In addition, the existence of a standard API allows JMS to interact with other standards. For example, in [ejb](/questions/tagged/ejb), there is such a thing as a [message-driven bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipko.html), which is an EJB which receives messages rather than method calls, and uses the JMS API to control the process.